# Have Powershell Read and Execute commands based on MS SQL Table Data?

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell

I am very new to Powershell and Powershell ISE. I have light experience with Object oriented programming languages and some SQL as well. Based on code examples I have found online, I have managed to have powershell connect to a Data Base and Run/Display a Query.

I am stuck here, I need Powershell to go through all the databases on the SQL server one by one, checking a specific table column for a "Processed" state. For now, as it sees this processed state appear, I want power shell to display the database name, and that is was processed. I want it to do this for all the databases and then stop once each database has a "processed" state in that specific cell.

I assume I will need some sort of array and a if else statement and much more. If it can populate an array with all database names. Then one by one remove them as they meet the "Processed" requirement. And the program continues to loop until all databases have met this requirement.

Below is the code I have currently.

Any Help is Appreciated!

```
    $DBServer = "SERVER.NAME"
    $databasename = "master"
    $uid = "USERNAME"
    $pwd = "PASSWORD"
    $Connection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection #Set new object to connect to sql database
    $Connection.ConnectionString ="server=$DBServer;database=$databasename; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;" 
    clear #clears console 
    Write-host "Connection Information:"  -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
    $Connection #Displays connection information


    ### Connect to Database and Run Query

    $SqlQuery = @"

    SELECT name
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

    "@

    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand #setting object to use sql commands
    $Connection.open()
    Write-host "Connection to database successful." -foregroundcolor green -backgroundcolor black
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $Connection.Close()
    $DataSet.Tables[0]
    $Connection.Close()
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample output that you would expect to see?

Comment: There is a table within each DB that contains a status field. This field is either in the table as "Processed" or "Not Processed".

I want the script to pull up a list of all the DBs on the server. Then one by one check that specific table in each DB for the "Processed" flag. Once it gets to the end of the list, I want it to loop back around and continue checking the DBs for that "Processed" flag. Any time it finds a DB with the processed flag, I want it to output (in power shell): "DB NAME has been processed". I want it to continue to check the list, until all DBs have been outputted.

Comment: Why not just do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Because this is just the first step. I then need powershell to connect to another server and run a data recycle job for each database as they show up as "Processed" on the other server. Im using Power-shell to bridge the gap between the two.

Comment: I would look at articles that talk about backing up all databases using powershell. The logic is the same. Sub out the backup piece with running the job on your other server.